# Jetpack Compose transparent NavBackStackEntry

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I use Compose Navigation library, even if I set my root view and NavHost to have transparent background color, I see white background.

What I want is ability to see through to the previous NavBackStackEntry. But I do not want to implement it as an overlay.

If you implement it as activity, you can have transparent activity.

[image: This is how I want it to look]

Comment: did you find a solution or workaround?